# JGit LogCommand sometimes callable is false after creation

Tags: java, jgit

It is very strange,

When I run

```
LogCommand log= new Git(repository).log();
```

it fails when do

```
log.call().iterator() since callable is false in LogCommand.
```

This happens randomly which is very strange.

Any one see this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your code, most certainly `callable` is `false` because you have already invoked the command.

If you look into the `LogCommand` source code, you'll see that `callable` is set to `false` at the end of the `call` method. And this is the only place where the flag is set.